# get multiple variables from a line using shell script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

i am trying to monitor my hosts through ping. the hosts information are in a mysql table. i m using fping command the code is as followings

```
#/bin/sh

id=$(mysql -B --column-names=0 -uroot -pPassword -D monitor -e "SELECT ipv4 FROM nics WHERE icmp=1");

result=$(fping -c 10 $id |grep 'xmt/rcv/%loss');

#echo $result;

for line in $result;

do

echo $line

done
```

the output is

`111.125.140.6 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 10/10/0%, min/avg/max = 234/234/235`

`123.135.140.7 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 10/0/100%`

`111.125.140.1 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 10/10/0%, min/avg/max = 230/231/231`

`111.125.130.2 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 10/10/0%, min/avg/max = 234/234/234`

now i want to get IP, loss and average record from each line and input the data in a new table

thanks in advance

Comment: actually i am a bit new and tried to give detail . but some errors was showing and cant post the question. i m trying again .

Comment: From my understanding, if getting data from each of the lines is what you need, you can look at some tools like `awk`

Comment: If you are parsing lines like `111.125.130.2 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 10/10/0%, min/avg/max = 234/234/234` then try to make `:|/` as your `FS` in `awk` . it may help

Answer (score 1):

Using a `while` loop (instead of a `for` loop) with `awk`:

```
while read -r line
    do declare $(awk '{split($0,a,"[%/ ,]"); print \
    "ip="a[1],"send="a[8],"rec="a[9],"loss="a[10],"min="a[17],"avg="a[18],"max="a[19]}' <<< $line);
    ## variables created: [ip, send, rec, loss, min, avg, max]
    ## test with: echo $ip, $send, $rec, $loss, $min, $avg, $max
    ## now you can insert the variables into your new SQL table:
    echo "INSERT INTO newtable (IP,SEND,REC,LOSS,MIN,AVG,MAX) \
    VALUES ('$ip','$send','$rec','$loss','$min','$avg','$max');"
done< <(printf '%s\n' "$result") | mysql -uroot -pPassword foobar
```

This will to declare individual variables from your `$line` strings which you can insert into SQL.

Comment: its showing error

test.sh: line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

test.sh: line 22: `done< <(printf '%s\n' "$result") | mysql -uroot -pPassword monitor'

Comment: @RazibShahriarRubence: It should work, [here’s an example](https://repl.it/repls/FocusedLiveFirm).